# can't add crud actions to event_calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I added the gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
bundled
rails generate event_calendar
migrated
changed

```
match '/calendar(/:year(/:month))' => 'calendar#index', :as => :calendar, :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/}
```

to

```
get '/calendar(/:year(/:month))' => 'calendar#index', :as => :calendar, :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/}
```

went to

```
http://localhost:3000/calendar/
```

and I got myself a pretty blingin calendar, was just wondering how do you now add crud actions to it? I have been looking at the documents and find it rather confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to want to make an Events Controller and define the CRUD actions inside there.